# How do I delay reCaptcha being marked valid until the backend check is done?

Tags: angular, recaptcha, angular-forms

I'm using [DethAriel's ng-recaptcha module](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha) to implement reCaptcha No Captcha in my reactive form. The docs don't do a great job of explaining where the backend check would occur. The reCaptcha widget, and thus the form, is marked valid simply by the user completing the challenge.

The setup is simply a formBuilder object:

```
public usernameForm = this.fb.group({
    username: ['', Validators.required],
    captcha: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Markup is also fairly simple:

```
<re-captcha formControlName="captcha" 
  (resolved)="onCaptchaResolved($event)" 
  [(ngModel)]="usernameForm.captcha"></re-captcha>
```

I'm using the `ngModel` directive to try and halt valid state until the backend check is done in `onCaptchaResolved`, but it doesn't work. The form control is set valid immediately upon the response from Google. The reactive forms example in the docs doesn't use `ngModel`, but I'm out of ideas.

Where does the backend check come into play here?

Comment: have you considered using an asynchronous validator on the captcha? I've never done this before, but it seems like the most straight-forward solution

Comment: I had considered [that](https://netbasal.com/how-to-integrate-recaptcha-in-your-angular-forms-400c43344d5c), but I hope to avoid reinventing the wheel by using this component (which seems to be under active development). The docs gave me the impression that I wouldn't have to write much additional code.